# How could you logout (youtube, twitter, etc...) sessions from your app in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to know if is possible logout sessions apps like Twitter, Youtube, Facebook (accounts) automatically from an app made in Android (Java or Kotlin).

I faced some alternatives, such as: 
 - create Users (manage multiple users)
 - use account manager class (in android 6.0 or higher you must pick an account and this is not ideally)
 - Delete app data folder for those apps

If someone has done something similar please let me know, thanks!!

Comment: Seems impossible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176996/android-facebook-4-0-logout-programmatically

Comment: Is similar, but It only refers to Facebook, I want to know for any session/apps

Comment: Do you mean sessions in the browser, sessions in other apps, or sessions within your app?

Comment: Sessions in other apps, for example logout session Netflix app from my own app